# How to fix the cut text in Scene Builder

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this button with border and text. If I make the button smaller the text starts to get cut, even though the border is not yet reaching the text. [image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZh5Y.png)

This is the fxml code:

```
<Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="194.0" styleClass="eventEditorVorspiel" stylesheets="@../css/style.css" text="VORSPIEL" textFill="WHITE">
```

and this the css:

```
-fx-font-size: 22pt;
-fx-border-width: 2;
-fx-border-color: white;
-fx-background-image: url("/icons/plus_ws.png");
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-background-size: 42 42;
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
-fx-background-position: left;
-fx-border-insets: 10px 0px 10px 0px 40px 0px 40px 0px ;
-fx-padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
```

## Found the solution:

The 15px in the css padding cut the text. I just removed the padding entirely and now it works.

Comment: Add fiddle of your code.

Comment: how do I add a fiddle and which code? I posted the fxml and css code of the button.

Comment: There are some guys who think every question about CSS is about HTML+CSS. You cannot create a JSfiddle for a javafx fxml.